После отправки ping интерфейс "просыпается"
Пытаюсь разобраться в сетях, возник очень странный вопрос. Chatgpt не подсказал ничего путного, в инете инфы нет (либо вопрос не правильно формулирую)
Имеется wmvare, 4 запущенных на нём сервера linux:
1.DHCP 192.168.0.1
2.DNS 192.168.0.11
3.SAMBA 192.168.0.4
4.Маршрутизатор с тремя интерфейсами (192.168.1.157 - бридж, смотрит в мой вайфай роутер, 192.168.0.14/24, 10.1.1.4/24), прописан ip.forward
Нужно соединение с сервером SAMBA с моей основной ОС windows.

Пингую маршрутизатор 192.168.1.157  - пинг идёт, так как в моей же сети 192.168.1.0/24
Пингую SAMBA пинга нет. Прописал маршрут:

192.168.0.3  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.157    192.168.1.127     41

Кидаю пинг снова - не идёт, кидаю трассу - * * *
Меняю метрику до 1, вдруг идёт на 0.0.0.0 - не вышло.
Посмотрел в wireshark. Там mac моего маршрутизатор, значит куда идти знает.
Отключил все что могло касаться сети на маршрутизаторе. NAT - не было, iptables - правил нет, apparmor - выключил, ufw - тоже. Не помогло.
Пингую с SAMBA мой хост 192.168.1.127
Пинг пошёл. С обоих сторон две

Выключил wake on lan на интерфейсе - не помогло. После перезагрузки роутера пинговать со своего хоста SAMBA так и не могу.
Это что такое ? Почему так ? Где посмотреть настройки ?
